# Codeigniter custom form validation rule returning false positive

Tags: php, codeigniter, validation, query-builder

I have several Codeigniter-based projects on which I've done this exact same thing, but for some reason in the most recent project I can't get it to work.

I have some customizations made directly on the CI core (yes, I know I should extend the core rather than modifying it, but it has worked so far and it makes it easier to start a new project with all modifications already in place). One of those modifications is an additional method on the `Form_validation` library (`system/libraries/Form_validation`) called `is_unique_sc` which allows to check if the submitted field is not already present on a table (just as the regular `is_unique` method) with the sole difference of allowing a `schema.table.field` argument rather than just `table.field` (this is needed since many projects I work on require using multiple separate schemas)

This is the custom method

```
public function is_unique_sc($str, $field)
{
    sscanf($field, '%[^.].%[^.].%[^.]', $schema, $table, $field);
    return isset($this->CI->db)
            ? ($this->CI->db->limit(1)->get_where($schema.'.'.$table, array($field => $str))->num_rows() === 0)
            : FALSE;
}
```

For comparison, this is the original `is_unique` method:

```
public function is_unique($str, $field)
{
    sscanf($field, '%[^.].%[^.]', $table, $field);
    return isset($this->CI->db)
        ? ($this->CI->db->limit(1)->get_where($table, array($field => $str))->num_rows() === 0)
        : FALSE;
}
```

This goes along the required modification on the `form_validation_lang` language file in case validation returns `false`:

```
$lang['form_validation_is_unique_sc']       = 'The {field} field must contain a unique value.';
```

I use this, like I said, on many projects with no issues until now.

However, on my most recent project, the new user creation is failing because of this rule:

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('new_email', 'Mail', 'required|trim|htmlspecialchars|strtolower|valid_email|is_unique_sc[accv_users.controllers.controller_email]');
```

The `is_unique_sc` rule is always returning `false` (and thus, displaying its validation error message) even if the email entered by the user is in fact unique. Removing the `is_unique_sc` rule allows the rest of the statement to validate properly, which discards the possibility of the whole `set_rules` statement to have an incorrect field name.

I have double and triple checked that the schema name is `accv_users`, the table name is `controllers` and the field name is `controller_email`. Query Builder is enabled as required by the method and the database connection is correctly configured and available.

Checking the output of the `sscanf()` function correctly assigns the schema name to `$schema`, the table name to `$table` and the field name to `$field`

For the sake of completeness, this is the field in the form view:

```
<div class="col-12 col-lg-3">
   <input class="form-control" type="email" id="new_email" name="new_email" placeholder="Mail" required>
</div>
```

The expected result is of course that when submitting the form with an email that doesn't already exist in the table, validation passes. validation should fail only when the email is already on the table.
I've searched a lot of similar cases in SO, but no solution has helped so far.

If anybody could help me pinpoint the issue, I'd be extremely grateful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After months of leaving this in oblivion (I worked around this failing validation by other means) I took another stab at it and cracked it!

It seems that in the latest versions of CI3, there's a bug that prevents the `is_unique` form validation rule from ever running correctly.

I did some deep digging and eventually found that this function:

```
public function is_unique($str, $field)
{
    sscanf($field, '%[^.].%[^.]', $table, $field);
    return isset($this->CI->db)
        ? ($this->CI->db->limit(1)->get_where($table, array($field => $str))->num_rows() === 0)
        : FALSE;
}
```

would ALWAYS return `false` (and thus, make the form validation fail) because `isset($this->CI->db)` was always returning a boolean `FALSE`, regardless of all database-related stuff being autoloaded and Query Builder being active.

The fix was simple. Just a single line of code in the function itself:

```
public function is_unique($str, $field)
{
    sscanf($field, '%[^.].%[^.]', $table, $field);

    // add the following line
    $this->CI->load->database();

    return isset($this->CI->db)
        ? ($this->CI->db->limit(1)->get_where($table, array($field => $str))->num_rows() === 0)
        : FALSE;
}
```

After adding that single line, the form validation started working correctly again. It'll still fail if the `$this->CI->load->database()` fails, which is to be expected considering that the `is_unique` rule (and my own custom rule too) depend on being able to run queries. But as long as the database connection is available, the rule works!